# Strong limit cardinals below the first inaccessible

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

This is from Thomas Jech's "Set Theory" - Third Millennium Edition - page 95 (Section on Mahlo Cardinals). If k is the least inaccessible, all strong limits  below it (if there are any) have to be singular. Understood. But he says the set of all these must be closed and unbounded. Why? In the extreme case, why can't k be the least strong limit cardinal which also happens to be regular? So the set of strong limits below k is empty. Alternatively, there are such strong limits, but these don't reach all the way up to k?

Comment: the first strong limit has cofinality $\omega$.

Answer (score 3):

*Short version*: The situations you describe in your last sentence would indeed contradict the claim, but it can't occur; meanwhile the situation described in your third-to-last sentence has no bearing on the problem since regularity isn't part of the definition of strong limit-ness. The claim is true, and is proved by reasoning about the combinatorics of strong limit cardinals.

---

*Long version*: First of all, if $\kappa$ is the least inaccessible then by definition it is the least regular strong limit cardinal; this is what "inaccessible" means. (OK fine it's what "*strongly* inaccessible" means, but that's what's usually meant when we say "inaccessible.") But this has no bearing on the claim: the claim is that

$$S=\{\lambda<\kappa:\lambda\mbox{ is a strong limit cardinal}\}$$

is club below $\kappa$, and you'll note that the word "regular" does not appear in the definition of $S$. **Strong limits are not in general regular**. For example, the first strong limit cardinal is $$\beth_\omega=\sup\{2^{\aleph_0}, 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}, 2^{2^{2^{\aleph_0}}}, ...\}$$ (do you see why?) and this has cofinality $\omega$.

The key points here are the following:

> **Claim 1**: A limit of strong limit cardinals is also a strong limit cardinal.

Proof sketch: if $\lambda$ is a limit of strong limit cardinals, clearly $\lambda$ is a limit cardinal. Now suppose $\mu<\lambda$; we want to show that $2^\mu<\lambda$. Since $\lambda$ is a limit of strong limits, there is some strong limit $\beta$ with $\mu<\beta<\lambda$; do you see how to proceed from here? $\quad\Box$

This shows that $S$ is closed. Now, why is $S$ unbounded below $\kappa$? Well, suppose $\sup(S)=\lambda<\kappa$. By Claim 1, $\lambda$ must be a strong limit cardinal (why?). Now consider:

> **Claim 2**: If $\lambda<\kappa$, then $\beth_\omega(\lambda)<\kappa$.

This follows from the strong limit-ness and regularity (or rather, uncountable cofinality) of $\kappa$.

> **Claim 3**: For all $\lambda$, the cardinal $\beth_\omega(\lambda)$ is a strong limit cardinal.

This is proved in the same way that we prove that $\beth_\omega$ is a strong limit cardinal.

Putting claims $2$ and $3$ together we get a contradiction with the assumption $\sup(S)<\kappa$; this gives that $S$ is unbounded below $\kappa$, and so we're done.

Comment: Here's another way to prove this: (1) ZFC proves that the class $\beth_\alpha$ for limit $\alpha$ is a closed and unbounded class of cardinals; (2) If $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal, then $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC which agrees with V on the $\beth$ numbers. $\square$

Comment: @AsafKaragila Indeed. To the OP: note that the way Asaf's answer differs from mine is that in his (1) we just need to argue that $\beth_\omega(\lambda)$ exists, rather than that it is $<\kappa$, so my claim (2) is rendered unnecessary. On the other hand, his claim (2) takes an argument (not a hard one) which isn't needed in my answer.

Comment: It is the law of conservation of work: you either work on this part or on that part, but no proof is without work.

Comment: Noah, your Claim 2 is: "If λ<κ, then ℶω(λ)<κ. This follows from the strong limit-ness of κ." Is it strong-limitness or regularity? The argument would be that the sequence is of w-length, so it cannot be cofinal in k, by k's regularity.  On the other hand, it may be possible that if k is a strong limit, power set of any particular cardinal below that would stay below it, but the sup. may be k itself?

Comment: @MangeshPatwardhan You're right, I meant to include regularity; fixed.

Comment: Yes, here uncountable cofinality suffices. But is strong-limitness also necessary?

Comment: @MangeshPatwardhan Yes: we need to know that $\theta<\kappa\implies 2^\theta<\kappa$. Strong limit-ness tells us that $\beth_n(\lambda)<\kappa$ for each finite $n$, and this is clearly necessary; regularity (or uncountable cofinality) then tells us that in fact $\beth_\omega(\lambda)<\kappa$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Right. I said that uncountable cofinality suffices, indeed it does. But we know k has uncountable cofinality because we know it's inaccessible (so uncountable) and regular. So while in general the claim can be proved even after by weakening regularity to uncountable cofinality, here we go from inaccessibility of k to conclude its cofinality is uncountable.

Comment: @MangeshPatwardhan Yes. But you *do* still need strong limit-ness. Uncountable cofinality applies *after* we've shown that $\beth_n(\lambda)<\kappa$ for each finite $n$, and this requires that $\kappa$ be a strong limit.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, now I understand. Both strong-limitness and uncountable cofinality are necessary. The only thing I wanted to point out in the last comment was that in this specific context, we actually start with k's regularity to conclude it has uncountable finality. But as you mentioned, in a general setting, your Claim 2 can be proved with only uncountable cofinality, without any reference to regularity.

Comment: @MangeshPatwardhan Yes, exactly. Note that regularity does not guarantee uncountable cofinality: $\omega$ is regular. But we're *also* assuming that $\kappa$ is uncountable, so that's the last little bit needed, and we've shown: **if $\kappa$ is a strong limit cardinal of uncountable cofinality then the set of strong limits below $\kappa$ is club in $\kappa$.**

Comment: Absolutely right